# Why doesn't my VB.Net code see the value that my SPROC is returning?

Tags: vb.net

I've written some logic into a sproc that returns either 1 or 0 for true/false.  Works great if I run it manually, but if I call it from VB I always get 0/false, no matter what the actual value the sproc returns.  Probably missing something silly, but I'm just not seeing it.  The code is partially copied from other code in our system that does work properly, but uses a dynamically constructed sproc call.  I'm attempting to modify that code to use parameterized sproc calls.

The sproc returns the value in the column named "Allowed".

The VB code (copied and sanitized for variable names/content) looks like:

```
Public Function sample(ByVal parm1 As String, ByVal parm2 As String) As Boolean                
    Dim Allowed As Boolean = False
    Try           
        Dim MyConnection As New SqlConnection(ConnString)
        Dim MyDataAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter("sproc", MyConnection)
        Dim DS As New DataSet
        MyDataAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        MyDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@parm1", SqlDbType.Char, 14))
        MyDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters("@parm1").Value = parm1
        MyDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@parm2", SqlDbType.Char, 30))
        MyDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters("@parm2").Value = parm2.ToUpper()
        MyDataAdapter.Fill(DS)
        If DS.Tables.Count > 0 Then
            If DS.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
                Allowed = Convert.ToBoolean(DS.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("Allowed"))
            End If
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        ' Real code has error handling here that's not getting hit
    End Try
    Return Allowed
End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are only returning a true/false you should use execute scalar. there is a good example here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-3

Comment: I like that the code is much shorter that way.  However, it doesn't work (same results as my listed code).

Comment: Perhaps you missed the fact that the column returned is named "Allowed", and is not the same as the SQL result (which returns 0 for all our sprocs).

Comment: if you are using the execute scalar it shouldn't matter what the column is called. Execute scalar will automatically take the first column of the first row that is being returned. Can you posted your executescalar code? You are sure the SP is actually returning a true when you are expecting it to?

Comment: A HA!  Got it.  Test data was missing leading zeroes...  Ugh.  Your approach works perfect and makes for much more attractive code!

Answer (score 1):

I would make sure to cast your value in the sproc as a bit something like:
select cast(1 as bit)

Select 1 and select Cast(1 as bit) will be two different things.